# How can I change default size of text field in symfony2 formType class

Tags: symfony

How can I change default text field size in symfony2 formType class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you try something like :

```
$builder->add('your_text_field', 'text', array(
    'attr' => array('size' => '25'),
));
```

Comment: my one is given bellow.......but i don't know why it doesn't work   ->add('insNo','text',array(
                'label'=>'Ins No.',
                'max_length'=>4,
                'attr'=>array(
                    'size'=>'5',
                   'placeholder'=>'Ins No.',
                   
                )
            ))